# why the num is wrong when I use bash -x

Tags: bash, wc

When I count process's  number to use  `wc -l` , The number is 2 in the command line, but I found it is 4 in the shell scripts, what's happened?

```
$ ps -ef |grep -v grep |grep etcd  |wc -l
2
```

```
$ bash -x count.sh etcd
++ ps -ef
++ grep -v grep
++ grep etcd
++ wc -l
+ num=4
+ case $1 in
+ echo 4
4
```

The shell script

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

num=$(ps -ef |grep -v grep |grep etcd  |wc -l)

case $1 in
etcd) 
    echo ${num}
;;

*) 
   echo  "other"

;;
esac
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are calling the script with an argument: `count.sh etcd`. The script itself will be part of the ps output, which does add to the results.

Use `pgrep`, it is meant for that

```
pgrep -c etcd
```

I further recommend to use the `-x` (exact match) argument, to prevent it from matching `etcdctl`, for example:

```
pgrep -xc etcd
```

---

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

num=$(pgrep -xc etcd)

case $1 in
etcd) 
    echo "${num}"
;;

*) 
   echo  "other"

;;
esac
```